# Qual a lógica para calcular a porcentagem de vitória, empate e derrota?

Tags: php, microsoft-excel

Estou querendo saber a lógica, de como calcular a porcentagem das tabelas de um jogo de futebol.

[image: Tabela da porcentagem dos jogos.]

Por exemplo, eu coloquei aqui uma tabelinha rápida do Excel só para demonstração. Em vermelho está a porcentagem real, e ao lado está a porcentagem que eu consegui.

Então minha dúvida é como chegar aos valores de 100% quando se ganha todas, 77% quando ganha 2 e empata 1 e quando é 44% quando ganha 1, empata 1 e perde 1.

Qual a lógica utilizada nesse cálculo? Eu tentei quebrar a cabeça mas nesse momento, mas não obtive resultado.

Comment: Você quer em PHP **ou** no Excel? Tem que se decidir, se não você fica ampliando a pergunta.

Comment: De onde vieram esses números? Quem disse que essa é a porcentagem real? Porque essas porcentagens de 77 e 44 não fazem sentido. O correto seria 66 e 33.

Comment: Se o problema é só de matemática, não está no escopo. Se é de programação, clique em [edit] e ponha somente um [mcve] do problema no post.

Comment: Bacco, colega. Essa pergunta já foi respondida faz tempo. Essa pergunta já era pra tá era fechada. Não sei porque está pendente se eu já marquei a resposta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para calcular a porcentagem neste caso, com 3 elementos, você calcula a diferença do item que está procurando em relação a soma total. Ex:

- 3 vitórias
- 4 derrotas
- 1 empate

Para saber a % de **vitórias**:

```
3 / (3 + 4 + 1)
3 / 8
0,375
37,5% de vitórias
```

Para saber a % de **derrotas**:

```
4 / (3 + 4 + 1)
4 / 8
0,5
50% de derrotas
```

Para saber a % de **empates**:

```
1 / (3 + 4 + 1) * 100
1 / 8
0,125
12,5% de derrotas
```

Logo:

```
37,5% + 50% + 12,5% = 100%
```

Comment: Ah! Entendi Diego. Eu estava tentando calcular nessa lógica que você mostrou aí. Mas eu estava fazendo de forma errada. A minha lógica era essa aí, só a execução que tava errada. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente não interessa mais ao colega, mas vou responder caso alguém pesquise:

Se for considerar a pontuação dos jogos de futebol atualmente, ou seja, 3 pontos para uma vitória, 1 ponto para o empate e 0 pontos para as derrotas, então fazemos o seguinte:

Calculamos o número máximo de pontos que uma equipe poderia conquistar:
Exemplo, se ela jogou 8 partidas, ela poderá conquistar no máximo 24 pontos =(8*3).

Temos então o número 24.

Agora, suponhamos que essa equipe nessas 8 partidas venceu 5, empatou 1 e perdeu 2. Nesse caso (segundo as regras do futebol) ela somou 16 pontos.

Agora é só dividir 16 por 24 e multiplicar por 100 para obter a porcentagem

=(16/24)*100= 66,66

Ou seja, essa equipe teve um aproveitamento de 66,66% nas 8 partidas que disputou.

Agora uma observação, caso você queira fazer esse cálculo utilizando uma base geral, sem utilizar o sistema de pontuação do futebol ou de outro esporte, dá pra colocar uma vitória como sendo 100%, um empate 50% e a derrota 0%. Se usarmos esse sistema no exemplo acima, por exemplo, teríamos =8*100%= 800% (que é o número máximo que daria para atingir), como o time venceu 5 partidas e empatou 2, ele teria 550%, aí é só dividir =550%/800% que daria 68,75%.

Embora o resultado seja diferente, ambos os cálculos estão corretos, pois utilizam bases diferentes.

Comment: Na verdade a resposta já foi respondida. E já consegui o que eu queria. O colega Diego já me ajudou. Já era pra essa pergunta tá fechada. Não sei porque está aberta ainda.